# When should one use the Actor model?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, functional-programming, actor, actor-model

When should the [Actor Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) be used?

It certainly doesn't guarantee deadlock-free environment.

Actor A can wait for a message from B while B waits for A.

Also, if an actor has to make sure its message was processed before moving on to its next task, it will have to send a message and wait for a "your message was processed" message instead of the straightforward blocking.

***What's the power of the model?***

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Given some concurrency problem, what would you look for to decide whether to use actors or not?

First I would look to define the problem... is the primary motivation a speedup of a nested for loop or recursion? If so a simple task based approach or parallel loop approach will likely work well for you (rather than actors).

However if you have a more complex system that involves dependencies and coordinating shared state, then an actor approach can help. Specifically through use of actors and message passing semantics you can often avoid using explicit locks to protect shared state by actually making copies of that state (messages) and reacting to them.

You can do this quite easily with the classic synchronization problems like dining philosophers and the sleeping barbers problem.  But you can also use the 'actor' to help with more modern patterns, i.e. your facade could be an actor, your model view and controller could also be actors that communicate with each other.

Another thing that I've observed is that actor semantics are learnable by most developers and 'safer' than their locked counterparts.  This is because they raise the abstraction level and allow you to focus on coordinating access to that data rather than protecting all accesses to the data with locks.  As an example, imagine that you have a simple class with a data member. If you choose to place a lock in that class to protect access to that data member then any methods on that class will need to ensure that they are accessing that data member under the lock.  This becomes particularly problematic when others (or you) modify the class at a later date, they have to *remember* to use that lock.

On the other hand if that class becomes an actor and the data member becomes a buffer or port you communicate with via messages, you don't have to remember to take the lock because the semantics are built into the buffer and you will very explicitly know whether you are going to block on that based on the type of the buffer.

-Rick

Answer (score 26):

The usage of Actor is "natural" in at least two cases:

1. When you can decompose your problem in a set of independent tasks.
2. When you can decompose your problem in a set of tasks linked by a clear workflow (ie. [dataflow programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow)).

For instance, if you process complex data using a series of filters, it is easy to use a pipeline of actors where each actor receives data from an upstream actor and sets data to a downstream actor.

Of course, this data-flow must not be linear and if a step is slow in your pipeline, instead you can use a pool of actors doing the same job. Another way of solving the load balancing problems would be to use instead a demand-driven approach organized with a kind of virtual [Kanban](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanban) system.

Of course, you will need synchronization between actors in almost all interesting cases, but contrary to the classic multi-thread approach, this synchronization is really "concrete". You can imagine guys in a factory, imagine possible problems (workers run out of the job to do, upstream operations is too fast and intermediate products need a huge storage place, etc.) By analogy, you can then find a solution more easily.

Comment: To add to your point, one of the advantages of object oriented programming is encapsulation of data and related functions. However, one still needs to "give life" to an object by calling one of its methods. We have a separate view of objects and processes there. Actors on the other hand are processes in their own right. This makes it easy to relate them to the real world.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an actor expert but here is my 2 cents when to use actor model:
Actor model is not suited for every concurrent application, for instance if you are creating an application which is multi threaded and works in high concurrency actor model is not made to solve the concurrency issue. 
Where actors really comes into play is when you are creating an event driven application. For instance you have an application and you are tracking what are users clicking in your application realtime. You can use actors to do activities realtime segregated by user, device or anything of your business requirement as actors are stateful. So, for example if some users lies in actors which clicked on `shirts` you can send them notification of some coupon. 
Also some applications where actors comes handy are : Finance (Pricing, fraud detection), multiplayer gaming.

Answer (score 1):

Actors are asynchronous and concurrent but does not guarantee message order or time limit as to when the message may be acted upon. Hence atomic transactions cannot be split into Actors.

If the application/task involves no mutable state then Actors are overkill as Actor frameworks go to great lengths to avoid race conditions.